# Detectron2: No instances in prediction

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, torch, detectron

I'm trying to train Detectron2 on a custom dataset that I annotated with [coco-annotator](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator). After training I wanted to predict Instances of my Image, but I dont get any shown.

Training:

```
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("TrashTron_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("TrashTron_val",)
# cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")  # Let training initialize from model zoo
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.00025  # pick a good LR
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 300    # 300 iterations seems good enough for this toy dataset; you will need to train longer for a practical dataset
cfg.SOLVER.STEPS = []        # do not decay learning rate
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 512   # faster, and good enough for this toy dataset (default: 512)
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 24  # only has one class (ballon). (see https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/datasets.html#update-the-config-for-new-datasets)
# NOTE: this config means the number of classes, but a few popular unofficial tutorials incorrect uses num_classes+1 here.

os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

Prediction:

```
test_data = [{'1191.jpg': '/content/datasets/val/1191.jpg',
              'image_id': 1308}]

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7   # set a custom testing threshold
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")  # path to the model we just trained
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 24
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
outputs = predictor(im)
# print(outputs["instances"].pred_densepose)
im = cv2.imread(test_data[0]["1191.jpg"])

v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
               metadata=MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]),
               scale=0.5,
               instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW)
out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
img = cv2.cvtColor(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1], cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)
```

The corresponding image is shown, but no instances.
Any suggestions? The overall evaluation scores aren't that great, but I picked the best class and there I also dont get any predictions...

Comment: Just to confirm - have you looked at `outputs["instances"]` to check if there are any instances predicted at all?

Comment: Could you add the input image as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to lower the threshold, since you have said that overall training scores were not great.

In this [answer in official repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/52#issuecomment-609742950), following code is suggested to change the threshold:

```
cfg.MODEL.TENSOR_MASK.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.5
```

at another [answer at the same thread](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/52#issuecomment-541453481), other thresholds are modified as well.

```
cfg.MODEL.RETINANET.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = args.confidence_threshold 
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = args.confidence_threshold 
cfg.MODEL.PANOPTIC_FPN.COMBINE.INSTANCES_CONFIDENCE_THRESH = args.confidence_threshold
```